# JAVA_HOME not being found when launching hbase. Any suggestions?

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hbase

I'm just playing around with hbase( on EC2) and am having a problem when I launch it. Here's what I get:

```
[root@domU-12-31-39-13-D6-62 ~]# sudo /etc/init.d/hadoop-hbase-master start
+======================================================================+
|      Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
|       > http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ <                      |
|                                                                      |
| HBase requires Java 1.6 or later.                                    |
| NOTE: This script will find Sun Java whether you install using the   |
|       binary or the RPM based installer.                             |
+======================================================================+
```

I looked up the error and installed openjdk 1.6 and set the java_home variable in my .bash_profile and in /etc/profile(just in case hbase is running as a different user). It seems to have taken effect:

```
[root@domU-12-31-39-13-D6-62 ~]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.4) (rhel-1.42.1.10.4.el6_2-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
[root@domU-12-31-39-13-D6-62 ~]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/bin/java
```

but I still get this error when launching hbase.  I'm not that famlair with java so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  If it helps, I'm using centos6 on ec2 and cloudera's repository for the hbase/hadoop packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` shouldn't point to the `java` executable ', but rather to the place where the rest of the java files can be found.

I think it's `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/`. I
 Think you can use `update-alternatives --display java` to show all javas installed.

Comment: Still no luck, I changed the JAVA_HOME to /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin as per the location in update-alternatives --display java but still no luck. When I launch from that path it works when I launch it directly from the command line

Comment: Not bin, the folder above bin! export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much Peter.  So just for my knowledge, packages want to know the top level folder so they can find the bin/lib,etc under it and not just the executable and then work its way up from there? or is this only java?

Comment: want to know something weird? it works when I run the command without sudo on the front but when I run sudo and then the command I still get the java_home error..so odd.

Answer (score 2):

Check your script /etc/init.d/hadoop-hbase-master and see where it trying to find java also your can run it in debug mode.

## sh -x /etc/init.d/hadoop-hbase-master start

Comment: Thanks that was helpful..pointing me in the right direction, here's the error "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory"   It has an extra bin in the path..but where is it getting that from? my .bash_profile is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have already set JAVA_HOME in bashrc and still it is not working, try setting it in /etc/environment file.

Answer (score 0):

You can hard code your JAVA path in your /etc/init.d/hadoop-hbase-master  script if you want to quick check.

Answer (score 0):

Probably $JAVA_HOME is pointing to a JRE home. Check to confirm if javac is present in the bin